# SQL format for decimal with comma to indicate decimals, only to digit

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I convert the decimal values to have some commas?

The number goes without comma to separate 1000's and has a comma to indicate decimals, only to digits.

For Example:  1324,35  (correct)
Instead of 1.324,35 (incorrect format) or 1,345.64 (incorrect format)

Comment: can you provide what you have so far to produce the above?

Comment: for example: 1324.3532  how to convert into 1324,35

Comment: it depends on your local language settings. You can also convert a number in order to use comma but it will be treated as VARCHAR instead of number: `REPLACE(CAST(1324.35 AS VARCHAR(20)), '.', ',')`

Comment: @VladimirKirov post your query. SQL Server *doesn't* have a specific format for decimal/numeric types. They are *binary* values. Formats apply only when *the code* converts numbers to strings, either explicitly through `CAST/CONVERT/FORMAT` or implicitly by assigning numbers to text fields/variables

Comment: @VladimirKirov if you really want to convert numbers to text, do so on the *client*. It's a lot easier to format text there, *and* determine the correct locale. Otherwise use the `FORMAT` function *with* the desired locale.

Comment: @VladimirKirov in any case NEVER USE REPLACE!!. This will **guarantee** your code will break when someone uses a different locale to read or worse, *write* decimal data. It's not the dot at fault anyway, it's using the wrong locale for the conversion

Comment: @B3S this `REPLACE` is a bad idea, guaranteed to cause bugs when someone, inevitably, uses a different locale.

Comment: @VladimirKirov besides, what you posted in the comment shows *rounding*, not formatting. If you want to round `1324.3532` to two digits, use `ROUND(somefield,2)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yep it actually is, but i think it's exactly the point the OP is looking for.

Comment: SELECT
 SUM(a.total_amount)
FROM p_order_payment_plan_payment a
INNER JOIN p_order_payment_plan plan ON plan.payment_plan_id = a.payment_plan_id AND plan.state = 'active'
WHERE (
(a.payment_type = 'monthly_payment' AND a.is_overdue = 'yes') OR a.payment_type = 'penalty') AND plan.order_id = ord.order_id
) AS overdue_amount

Comment: @VladimirKirov there are no decimal to string conversions in this query. And please, update the question and include the actual query.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an appropriate culture argument to `FORMAT()`.  Many European countries use commas as decimal separators, so something like this works:

```
select FORMAT(12345.8, '#.00', 'fr-fr')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using SQL server 2012 and up, you can use the [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function, 
like in:

```
 FORMAT (YourColumn, "#,###")
```

Comment: This will still use the localized format, ie `.` or `,` for decimals. `FORMAT` is appropriate because it accepts a third parameter for the desired locale